# Question marks in training phrases in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

What is the best practice on using question marks in case of questions in Dialogflow's training phrases - should I use them or not?

My observation is that if I will add training phrases with question mark (eg. "What is the weather?") then sometimes same user sentences without question mark won't be recognized as specific intent. On the other hand when I will add training phrases without question marks, they will be properly recognized regardless of using question mark.

**Example 1**

```
Training phrase: "What is the weather?"
User question: "What is the weather?" (recognized)
User question: "What is the weather" (not recognized)
```

**Example 2**

```
Training phrase: "What is the weather"
User question: "What is the weather?" (recognized)
User question: "What is the weather" (recognized)
```

Comment: According to me, add both as training phrases to get more accurate results.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid duplication of training phrases (with and without question mark) because it would be harder to maintain. I would like to use only training phrases without question marks but currently I have no guarantee that user sentences with question marks will always trigger proper intent.